# How to launch Javascript on each page ( jQuery Mobile )

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i am new to this place but already searched for answers on google and here, but i do not find a single answer that helped me (even though this question was asked alot of times!).

So my problem is, i have been making a jquery mobile page that i want to use as an app later on. I use 3 different pages (index.html, page2.html, page3.html) and i want to fire some javascripts each time these pages are clicked in the navigation.

i found alot of posts regarding this problem but most of them were kinda old (~2011) and the solutions i found didnt work.

here is what i already tried:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

is the head of every page i use. in the doc of jquery mobile is written, that you have do insert your script between jquery and jquery mobile to be executed (js.js is my custom js). this script will only work on the first page, but i need it to run on every single page, because i exchange text on each page when some events happen.

after that i tried to put my code in the div data-role="page" so it will be executed every time, but this also didnt work. when i just put some console.log() in it (between $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){ ), the postings wont fire on every pagechange, but will fire in a ² way when i travel back to the original page (after 5 pagechanges, the log message will be put like 60 times in the console).

```
function packungSpeichern() {

var formPackung = new Object;

formPackung.inhalt = document.getElementById("inhalt").value;
formPackung.date  = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");

localStorage.setItem( "formPackung", JSON.stringify(formPackung) );
```

}

here is an example out of my custom js file. i can only use this script on the first page i launch, but not on ALL pages :/

i hope you understand what i want, my english isnt the best at all :)

Comment: how did you try to put the JavaScript code inside your DIV? can you provide an example?

Comment: `<script>
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
 console.log("test2");
});
</script>` When i put this on every page with page one "test1", page 2 "test2" and page3 "test3", i can see in the console that on a page change the event of the page that i came from will also be triggert, but when i go back to the page i came from the log wont be triggert. i just dont understand why :)

Comment: What do you mean by going back? Do you mean you use the back-button of your browser, or you reload the page by clicking a link?

Comment: @user1677406 you need to put `<script src="js/js.js"></script>` and possibly also `<script src="js/moment.js"></script>` into all of your pages for it to be executed on each page

Comment: [link](http://schnebdreleg.hostingsociety.com/pilmon/index.html) Here is a link to the page. Its in german, sorry. So when you launch the first page (ubersicht) you can see in the console "test". when you go to packung in the navigation the console says "test test2". when you go back to ubersicht , it does nothing. you go back to packung it does test test 2 test2.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter all my pages can stand for themself, so i already did put those scripst into every head of the pages. but in the jquery mobile doc is stated that the head will be ignored after the first page.

Comment: @user1677406 no, not the HEAD - jQuery does not process scripts included in head when called via AJAX - you need to include them into the page body - i.e. into the actual page DIV of your JQM pages

Comment: @ZathrusWriter yes i understand that, but as you can see on my page, putting scripsts inside the page id div will end up in a very strange behavior. `$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
 console.log("test2");
});` for example

Comment: that's because if you put *that code* into page div, you're binding the console.log() to each pagechange again and again, essentially multiplying it - that part need to be in your HTML HEAD only :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter but when i put this into the head, this will only work an a single page ?! i am confused :) can you give me an example? i now wrote that console.log only in the head of the first page. when i travel to the second page, the script will be executed again. when i go back to the first page, the script will not load. and that is exactly the behavior i need to run my scripst :/

Answer (score 0):

In HEAD of the **first page** in JQM:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

In BODY (page DIV) of **each of the JQM pages** (anywhere at the bottom, like in footer etc.):

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
     </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you put this into your HEAD, you will tell jQuery to execute this script **once per page change**:

```
$(document).bind("pageshow", function( event, ui ){
    console.log('A page has changed!');
}
```